# User role wise permission for controller function in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am working with laravel5.4. I need to create role wise permission for every method.

Here I have created one middleware **(roles)** as below :

**CheckRole.php**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $role = array_slice(func_get_args(), 2);
    if ( ! User::find(auth()->id())->hasAnyRole($role))
    {    
        return response("Insufficient permission",401);
        session()->flash('message',"You have no permission to access");
        return redirect('/');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

I have one controller as **CompanyController** :

**CoompanyController.php**

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function (Request $request, $next) 
    {
        $this->user = \Auth::User();
        //print_r($this->user);exit;
        if($this->user['userrole_id'] == 1)
        {
            $this->middleware('roles:superadmin');      
        }
        else if ($this->user['userrole_id'] == 3) 
        {
            $this->middleware('roles:supportperson',['only' => ['index']]);
        }
        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

Here, if login user is **superadmin** than he can access all the function of controller. And If login user is **supportperson** than he can access only **index** method.

So how can I set permission to function for different rolewise using same middleware?

Comment: IMHO laravel ships with a fully configurable Authorisation system. There is no need for a custom middleware. See here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization

Comment: @dparoli I am new  in laravel so i don't know how to use it. So i user middleware.

Comment: first rule is don't reinvent the wheel, laravel codebase is a large beast to fight, read the docs before any customization.

Comment: @dparoli Ok. thanks

Answer (score 0):

use https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust

Entrust is a succinct and flexible way to add Role-based Permissions to Laravel 5.